# phpunit: getMockBuilder::setMethods() is deprecated

Tags: phpunit

In phpunit 9.6 `setMethods()` is deprecated ...

How to rewrite this test?

```
/**
 * @dataProvider provideGetDataMaxSizeInBytesData
 * @param int $expectedResult
 * @param string $maxSize
 * @return void
 */
public function testGetDataMaxSizeInBytes(int $expectedResult, string $maxSize): void
{
    $mock = $this->getMockBuilder(Mage_Uploader_Helper_File::class)
        ->setMethods(['getDataMaxSize'])
        ->getMock();

    $mock->expects($this->once())->method('getDataMaxSize')->willReturn($maxSize);
    self::assertSame($expectedResult, $mock->getDataMaxSizeInBytes());
}
```

It works, but i am not so happy with using old methods ;)